# How to assign '-' is equal to ' ' for string class compare, is this possible?

Tags: c++, string, class

I am comparing two strings, str1 and str2, using the string.compare function in #string.  Is there a way to force the class to think that `'-'` is the equivalent of `' '`.  Looking at the member functions of char_traits I thought that the .assign would allow me to accomplish this but it is acting as if I am saying, `str1='-';` or `str1=' ';`.  I would prefer not to rewrite my own string handling class.

Comment: I think it does comparisons by comparing character values; meaning you would have to make it think that `45 == 32`. Can you not make a copy of the string and replace all occurrences of `'-'` with `' '`, then compare?

Comment: @Chad: It's a space, so `32`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit AH! Couldn't tell there was a space there!

Comment: @Chad: Well, there's no such thing as `''` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities, depending whether you want this behavior:

- once
- encoded in the class

If you want to behavior once: simply use your own (custom) algorithm:

```
bool isSpace(char i) { return i == '-' or i == ' '; }

int compare(std::string const& left, std::string const& right) {
  typedef std::string::const_iterator ConstIterator;
  typedef std::pair<ConstIterator, ConstIterator> Result;

  size_t const size = std::min(left.size(), right.size());

  Result const r = std::mismatch(left.begin(),
                                 left.begin() + size,
                                 right.begin(),
                                 [](char a, char b) {
                                   return a == b or (isSpace(a) and isSpace(b));
                                 });

  if (r.first == left.begin() + size) { // equal up til the end, shorter wins
    return left.size() < right.size() ? -1 :
          (left.size() == right.size() ? 0 : 1);
  }

  // not equal until the end
  return *r.first < *r.second ? -1 : 1;
}
```

If this behavior need be encoded within the class itself, you need to use `basic_string` and provide a custom trait class.

The traits class provides a `static int compare ( const char_type* s1, const char_type* s2, size_t n);` function that is used by `std::string::compare` under the hood.

So for example:

```
struct MyTraits: char_traits<char> // too lazy to reimplement everything
{
  static int compare(const char_type* s1, const char_type* s2, size_t n);
  // definition can be trivially derived from the above version
};

typedef std::basic_string<char, MyTraits> MyString;
```

Of course, `MyString` is then completely incompatible with other `std::string`.

---

Frankly, if you can, simply "normalize" your string and decide whether you'll use '-' or ' '. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I really do not have a choice, I have to handle the '-' as that is what was used in name entries in our database, but our analysist do not use them when they setup there runs, so I need my software to recognize that, ex. PC-Eff T-P is the equivilant of PC Eff T P, as it was it was thinking it was Turbidity :P

Comment: @John: in designing typical architecture, one point that comes back over and over is "adapting" the external representation of data to the custom in-memory representation. For example, the DB layer could simply replace the '-' by ' ' as the records are pulled in, and then all your worries would go away. This validation/normalization of inputs is pretty common :)

Comment: I wish `std::basic_string` could be implicitly constructed from a `std::basic_string` with different char/traits/allocator.  That would simplify a lot of things.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I am not a huge fan of implicit constructors in general, but in this particular case I might be tempted :)

Answer (score 4):

What about copying and replacing all occurrences of "-" with " " before comparing the two strings?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the library for such a specific use case, but it's easy to do it yourself:

1. Make a copy of both strings. In each, replace all `'-'` with `' '`. Then perform the comparison on those strings;
2. Alternatively, make your *own* function that iterates through each character and performs a lexicographic comparison with the additional semantics you've described. This has the benefit of not requiring string copies, but is going to be more code and possibly more error-prone.

Comment: I believe it is possible by using a custom `char_traits`.  Isn't that what it's for?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Probably, but then don't you need a new `std::basic_string` instantiation that uses those traits? Necessitating a copy? (Well, you could make the strings _originally_ use those traits, but this would surely violate POLS) Or are traits a feature of the comparison? I forget.

Comment: You're right that it is a new class that would require a copy.  Replacing them is _much_ faster, or using a custom comparison as you say.  I also see it as slightly more error prone.  Tradeoffs either way.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to *fold* the strings, i.e. simple replace all "-" with " " before comparing them.

Answer (score 1):

The standard C++ library provide powerful algorithms for this. It seems you want to use `std::mismatch()` together with a custom predicate considering '-' and ' ' to be identical. This would look something like this:

```
bool pred(char c0, char c1) {
    return c0 == c1
          || (c0 == '-' && c1 == ' ')
          || (c0 == ' ' && c1 == '-');
}

std::string const& s(s0.size() < s1.size()? s0: s1);
std::string const& l(s0.size() < s1.size()? s1: s0);
auto p = std::mismatch(s.begin(), s.end(), l.begin(), pred);
```

Following this, `p` is a pair of iterator pointing at the first char which differs (or the end iterator). To determine which string sort before or after you'd just evaluate the result.

The interface is a bit annoying in that the shorter sequence needs to first: there should be constraints for both ends.

Answer (score 0):

(community-wiki, feel free to contribute.)

You can define a new type of string, based on a new type of char. The following compiles and seems to run, but maybe there are some things missing or wrong. The goal is to define a string class where hyphens are automatically converted to spaces.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct newchar {
        char c;
        bool operator <(const newchar &other) const {
                return this->c < other.c;
        }
        newchar(char c_): c(c_) {
                fixme();
        }
        newchar(): c('\0') {}
        newchar & operator = (const newchar &in) {
                this->c = in.c;
                fixme();
                return *this;
        }
        void fixme() {
                if(c=='-')
                        c = ' ';
        }
};

struct newstring : basic_string<newchar> {
        string toCharString() const {
                std :: string s;
                for(const_iterator i = this->begin(); i != this->end(); i++) {
                        char c = i->c;
                        s += c;
                }
                return s;
        }
};
ostream& operator<< (ostream & os, const newstring &ns) {
        os << ns.toCharString();
        return os;
}

int main() {
        newstring s;
        s.compare(s);
        s += 'k';
        cout << '<' << string() << '>' << endl;
        cout << '<' << s << '>' << endl;
}
```